# Github Actions Bicep deployment: "What-if" fails to create Key Vault; "Create" fails with exit code 1

Tags: github-actions, azure-rm-template, azure-bicep, azure-service-principal

It succeeds when I manually execute Bicep deployment with the following command:

az login
az deployment group what-if --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME --template-file ./infrastructure/bicep/main.bicep --parameters ./infrastructure/bicep/params.json

az deployment group create (with same arguments) fails with exit code 1 and no logged msg.

I then create a Service Principal and I set it as a Github Actions secret which I am supplying to my workflow for authentication with Azure/cli:

az ad sp create-for-rbac --name azure-contributor-github-service-principal --role contributor --scope /subscriptions/$SUBSCRIPTION_ID

Then execution of the same deployment but now automated fails with the following
log message:

"Multiple errors occurred: BadRequest. Please see the details.
BadRequest - The specified KeyVault '/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/<my_rg_name>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<my_kv_name>' could not be found."

The Bicep script indeed contains a declaration for a KeyVault resource named <my_kv_name>.
To me, it seems that when I use az cli and login with (az login) my Azure Portal User account the cli is already authorized to have Key Vault-related permissions. GitHub though using the Service Principal that I created especially for that purpose, doesn't have sufficient permissions even if I create it as --role owner.
I struggle to find more debugging information.
Any idea what I am missing?

UPDATE #1:

Considering @4c74356b41's answer I added in my Bicep code an access policy that sets permissions to the Service Principal for secrets.
Unfortunately I receive the same result.

```
resource keyVaultAccessPolicyForSecrets 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies@2022-07-01' = {
  name: '${keyVault.name}/policy'
  properties: {
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        applicationId: spPolicyAppId
        objectId: spPolicyObjectId
        tenantId: spPolicyTenantId
        permissions: {
          secrets: [ 'all' ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

UPDATE #2:

I managed to make the Bicep file deployable, but still I had to change its appearance. I believe the root cause of the issue is not related to Service Principal permissions to operate with the Key Vault that the script creates. Here is why I think so:

File structure of the Bicep Code:

- core.bicep - responsible for the creation of a Container Registry, a Key Vault, and a Key Vault Secret
- aca.bicep - responsible for the creation of a Log Analytics Workspace, a Container App Environment, and a Container App (with configured MS Default CA Image)
- main.bicep - where

1. via "module" I am referencing the core.bicep file which as I
   mentioned creates the Key Vault.
2. I create an existing Key Vault resource a prop of which I need to use as an input param to the next module
3. via "module" keyword I am referencing the aca.bicep file which I use to create the rest of the resources.

main.bicep:

```
module core 'core.bicep' = {
  name: 'core'
  params: {
    location: location
    solution: solution
    spPolicyAppId: spPolicyAppId
    spPolicyObjectId: spPolicyObjectId
    spPolicyTenantId: spPolicyTenantId
  }
}

resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01' existing = 
{
  name: core.outputs.KeyVaultName
}


module devAca 'aca.bicep' = {
  name: 'devAca'
  dependsOn: [
    core
  ]
  params: {
    env: 'dev'
    location: location
    project: project
    solution: solution
    containerRegistryName: core.outputs.ContainerRegistryName
    containerRegistryPassword: 
keyVault.getSecret(core.outputs.ContainerRegistrySecretName)
    imageName: imageName
    imageTag: imageTag
  }
}
```

Having this structure during the deployment is throwing already the mentioned message. When I took out the code from the subfiles and replaced the modules with it, the deployment started passing successfully.
Moreover, I removed the Key Vault Policy and the infrastructure still deploys successfully including the Key Vault and the Secret in it.

So my conclusion, for now, is that I am somehow misusing the "module" keyword

Answer (score 1):

Azure Key Vault got its own data plane permissions, you need to grant your Service Principal access to secrets\certificates\keys (not sure what you are puling) in the KV (get\list).

reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-portal

Comment: considering your answer, I created an AccessPolicy in my Bicep file granting 'all' permissions on 'secrets' for the Github Service Principal. The result is the same for now. Can you please take a look at the sample? (Post updated)

Comment: its really hard to tell what is wrong with the information provided, actually now when I look at your error it seems like you might have a typo in the kv name somewhere, because that error doesnt say not enought permissions or something like that, it says not found

Comment: I figured out what solves my issue, though I still cannot explain it to myself and I'd like to learn what is the root cause. (Post updated.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide full KeyVault bicep file, we can't be sure if it's Bicep issue or something else. Try this Bicep file below with your parameters, it should create a KeyVault and Access Policy. If it fails, then maybe your user (or service principle) is missing some rights in Azure?
Check [App registration API permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#more-on-api-permissions-and-admin-consent), you might need Application.ReadWrite.All or Azure KeyVault permission.

```
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2022-07-01' = {
  name: keyVaultName
  location: location
  properties: {
    tenantId: azureTenantId
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        objectId: ownerObjectId
        tenantId: azureTenantId
        permissions: {
          secrets: secretsPermissions
        }
      }
    ]
    sku: {
      name: keyVaultSkuName
      family: 'A'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've already tested this syntax and it didn't change anything in terms of the error that I receive. Finally, I figured out what solves my issue, though I still cannot explain it to myself and I'd like to learn what is the root cause. (Post updated.)